# Exporting/Importing a WordPress database to reproduce a site on another machine

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mamp

I am using WP 4.8 and using MAMP server. 
Exporting Database:

I exported the database using the following steps:
-Select folder
-Select export tab
-After Clicking the radio button for 'Custom', I select 'Save output to file'(I leave the defaults)

[image: MAMP screenshot]

Importing the DB (on the other machine):
(after decompressing a new wp site-naming it -and saving the wp-config.php)

-Open MAMP and choose the 'Import' Tab and select the backed up SQL file and press 'GO'

The following error:

```
Error

SQL query:

--
-- Database: `MyAceEL_db`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1046 - No database selected
```

So, either the problem might be either my export options or possibly an older version of MAMP on the laptop I'm trying to duplicate the site onto.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: import screen]

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell MySQL which of your possibly many databases it should apply this import (restore) to. So edit the file and add

```
USE `databasename`;
```

on the first line, and then import the file using `phpMyAdmin` or whatever you are using

Comment: First I should Creat a database by that name and THEN import right?

Comment: Yes, sorry I assumed you would have dont that.

Comment: Ok, this time after attempting to do the import INTO the new folder named for the DB it's giving the same error. Is it possilbe both machines have a different localhost setting? One at 8889 the other at 3306

Comment: If your tool is connected to the correct MYSQL then the port is irrelevant I think. Show the top of your `.sql` file please

Comment: I just added another screenshot to the above question.

Comment: It might be simpler to use the MYSQL command line interface `> mysql -uroot -p < MyAceEL_db.sql`